# offset text annotations created by matplotlib.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I am creating an arrow with a text annotation with annotate in matplotlib and want to offset the text from the arrow end.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.annotate(
    "test",
    xy=(0.2, 0.2),
    xytext=(0.5, 0.5),
    arrowprops=dict(
        arrowstyle="simple",
        facecolor="black",
    )
)

plt.show()
```

The text created here only goes to the end of the arrow. Is there a way to offset it with manual coords?

Comment: Why don't you use `plt.text` to put the text manually wherever you want? You can leave the text part in `annotate` blank by replacing `"test"` by `""` and then use `plt.text`

Comment: This is a solution, but I was looking if some keyword in `annotate` can do it.

Comment: You may play around with the `relpos` argument. But it might cause more headaches than creating two annotations, one for the arrow, one for the text.